# iphone image loading slow in webapp and safari

Tags: javascript, css, angular, loading

I am creating a PWA for android and ios. In android there is no image loading issue.. but in ios safari and web app there is an delay in loading images.
(Suppose I have 5 images in a row. 1st image will load after that 2nd image and then 3rd and on). I want my whole component to load after all the images are placed in there tag.

for this i did something like this

.ts file

```
// data = [{imgSrc:'local address'},..]
public loaded: boolean = false;

this.getData.subscribe((data) => {
  this.images = data;
  this.loaded = true;
  // tried like this also  setTimeout(() => loaded = true, 1000); 
});
```

.html file

```
<loader *ngIf="!loaded"></loader>
<div *ngIf="(loaded)">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of images;let i=index;">
      <span [style.backgroundImage]="'url('+ item.imgSrc +')'" </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you want to wait for all o the images to load? That doesn't seem like best practice.

Comment: In my UI, white blank screen appear before loading image.I don't want it... i want my component to appear with all content.

Comment: what is the size of each images?.

Comment: 18KB @SureshKumarAriya

Comment: It's the expected  behavior. delay denotes the time taken to download the images and update the DOM. If you want faster DOM updates. Instead of span, can you use <img src""/>

Comment: its working fine in android with no delay.. but in safari browser and webapp..there is this delay.

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya i tried img tag also.. Same behavior

Comment: Hi! You solved this problem? I have same issue.

Answer (score 0):

First You can preload those images.

```
    let images = new Array();
    function preload(preloadImages) {
        for (i = 0; i < preloadImages.length; i++) {
            images[i] = new Image()
            images[i].src = preloadImages[i];
        }
    }
    this.getData.subscribe( (data)=>{   
      this.preload(data);   // this will preload the images
      setTimeout(()=>{
          this.images = [{imgSrc:'local address'},..];
          this.loaded = true;
     }, 500);
    });
```

Comment: I tried preloading images but behaviour remains same.. loading perfectly in android but slowly in ios safari.

Comment: I have issues like you. Do you know how to solve it yet?